# NetBeans source formatting code block without formatting

Tags: php, netbeans, formatting, code-formatting

Is it possible to be used some kind of custom tag (example: ) in the code, where NetBeans code formatter to not apply the rules for formatting. This is needed for some specific source code blocks, where is not needed formatting, but Netbeans IDE always apply the formatting on the entire document. 
Any suggestions?

Thanks